# How to change figure name to image name in Matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I want to change figure name to name of the image `I = imread`is reading in the following code:

```matlab
I = imread("6hearts.jpg");
I = rgb2gray(I);

[Ir, Ic]=size(I);
if (Ic > Ir)
    I = imrotate(I,270);
end

srcFile = dir('C:\Users\umut8\Desktop\Deneme2*.jpg');
for i = 1:length(srcFile)
    filename = strcat("C:\Users\umut8\Desktop\Deneme2",srcFile(i).name);
    T = rgb2gray(imread(filename));
    [Tr, Tc]=size(T);
    temp = 0;
    if (Tc > Tr)
        T = imrotate(T,270);
        Temp = Tc;
        Tc = Tr;
        Tr = Temp;
    end
    R = normxcorr2(T,I);

    if (find(R > 0.75))
        R = imcrop(R,[Tc Tr Ic Ir]);
        [r, c, v] = find(R==(max(max(R))));
        RGB = insertShape(I, 'rectangle',[c, r, Tc, Tr],'LineWidth', 3, "Color", "Red" ,'Opacity',0.7 );

        figure(3);
        imshow(RGB)
    end
end
```

I want the title of the `figure3` to be the "6hearts" in this spesific example.

Comment: Are you looking for the function `title()`?

Comment: Yes but how i change title name with matching template name in my loop?

Comment: Just pass whatever name you want as an argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to add a
`title(filename)`
to your code. Depending on what you are intending, you can call a `break` afterwards to end the `for`-loop as soon as you found a matching template.
If not, it might be helpful to open separate figures and give them distinct names, e.g. `figure('Name' , strcat("6hearts: ", filename))`